# SQL query, joins without "on" clause and some with "on" clause

Tags: sql

I need some confirmation that this query is doing what I think it is.  Today I learned of this "old school" method of using a comma to join tables - and they do not have an on-clause specified. Yet, some other tables are also joined and do have on-clauses. Here is the query:

```
SELECT a.Col1, a.Col2, b.Col3
FROM b, a
JOIN c ON c.Name = a.Name
AND c.ID = a.ID
```

My understanding from my research so far, is that the comma represents a cross join, hence there needs not a column equality specifier ("on" clause) because a cross join simply joins each row from the first table to each row from the second table.

...so then, when applying the joins for table c, do those get applied before or after the cross join, or does it matter?

What would be a re-written example of this that uses the "Inner Join" "Cross Join" words instead of the commas?

Comment: Normally these old style (we are talking 25 years old) queries would include the join in the where clause, such as `where b.x=a.x`. But as @gordon said in this case there is no such join so its just a cross join. You sure that's what they intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write the query is:

```
SELECT a.Col1, a.Col2, b.Col3
FROM b CROSS JOIN
     a INNER JOIN c
     ON c.Name = a.Name AND c.ID = a.ID;
```

There is no need to learn about commas.  They are obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: Great, thank you sir!  Unfortunately my job is support a software application that has a lot of these statements, and I have a feeling I'm going to be the one stuck rewriting all the codes in the near future when we're forced to upgrade. But, this helps!

Comment: @PBJ . . . In general, you can replace `,` with `cross join`.  However, the better rewrite is to put the join conditions in the `on` clause.